# running the publicly available PCL RANSAC code & saving the result not working

Tags: visual-studio-2010, point-cloud-library, ransac

I am trying to use the publicly available code of RANSAC for PCL from here: http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/random_sample_consensus.php

However, I am omitting the 3D viewer portion. The problem I am facing is that I cant save the result & also when I check the final point cloud size, it`s showing zero. Here is the code:

```
#include <pcl/sample_consensus/ransac.h>
#include <pcl/sample_consensus/sac_model_plane.h>
#include <pcl/sample_consensus/sac_model_sphere.h>
#include <pcl/visualization/pcl_visualizer.h>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  // initialize PointClouds
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr final (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);

  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> final_result = *final; 

  // populate our PointCloud with points
  cloud->width    = 500;
  cloud->height   = 1;
  cloud->is_dense = false;
  cloud->points.resize (cloud->width * cloud->height);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < cloud->points.size (); ++i)
  {
    if (pcl::console::find_argument (argc, argv, "-s") >= 0 || pcl::console::find_argument (argc, argv, "-sf") >= 0)
    {
      cloud->points[i].x = 1024 * rand () / (RAND_MAX + 1.0);
      cloud->points[i].y = 1024 * rand () / (RAND_MAX + 1.0);
      if (i % 5 == 0)
        cloud->points[i].z = 1024 * rand () / (RAND_MAX + 1.0);
      else if(i % 2 == 0)
        cloud->points[i].z =  sqrt( 1 - (cloud->points[i].x * cloud->points[i].x)
                                      - (cloud->points[i].y * cloud->points[i].y));
      else
        cloud->points[i].z =  - sqrt( 1 - (cloud->points[i].x * cloud->points[i].x)
                                        - (cloud->points[i].y * cloud->points[i].y));
    }
    else
    {
      cloud->points[i].x = 1024 * rand () / (RAND_MAX + 1.0);
      cloud->points[i].y = 1024 * rand () / (RAND_MAX + 1.0);
      if( i % 2 == 0)
        cloud->points[i].z = 1024 * rand () / (RAND_MAX + 1.0);
      else
        cloud->points[i].z = -1 * (cloud->points[i].x + cloud->points[i].y);
    }
  }

  std::vector<int> inliers;

  // created RandomSampleConsensus object and compute the appropriated model
  pcl::SampleConsensusModelSphere<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr
    model_s(new pcl::SampleConsensusModelSphere<pcl::PointXYZ> (cloud));
  pcl::SampleConsensusModelPlane<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr
    model_p (new pcl::SampleConsensusModelPlane<pcl::PointXYZ> (cloud));
  if(pcl::console::find_argument (argc, argv, "-f") >= 0)
  {
    pcl::RandomSampleConsensus<pcl::PointXYZ> ransac (model_p);
    ransac.setDistanceThreshold (.01);
    ransac.computeModel();
    ransac.getInliers(inliers);
  }
  else if (pcl::console::find_argument (argc, argv, "-sf") >= 0 )
  {
    pcl::RandomSampleConsensus<pcl::PointXYZ> ransac (model_s);
    ransac.setDistanceThreshold (.01);
    ransac.computeModel();
    ransac.getInliers(inliers);
  }

  // copies all inliers of the model computed to another PointCloud
  pcl::copyPointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>(*cloud, inliers, *final); 
  cout << final->size() << endl;  // show the size
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> final_result = *final;
  pcl::io::savePCDFile ("final_result.pcd", final_result);  // save

  return 0;
 }
```

any idea why this is not working?

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something that will be meaningful if it appears in the search results for a future user of this site. "Publicly available PCL RANSAC code" is a statement, not a description of the problem you're having or a question. You've identified the PCL and RANSAC information in the tags for the question, so including it in the title is both redundant and meaningless. The "publicly available code" that remains provides no information about your questions topic or the problem. Thanks.

Comment: In general it is easier to help when you post a minimal example of compilable code (this one is not: missing headers and double declaration of `final_result`).

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass -s or -sf as argument when running the compiled program.